# ConstraintLayout глючит, что делать?

Tags: android, android-layout

`ConstraintLayout` глючит, что делать?

Допустим я открыл xml, оформил разметку через `ConstraintLayout`, сохранил проект закрыл студию. Запустил и там такая бредядина отображается. Кликаешь на `ImageView` его там нету вообще. Все съежилось в кучу, короче бред полный. Как быть?

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` в стадии бэта-тестирования. Вы пользуетесь им на свой страх и риск, претензии не принимаются, багрепорты по адресу разработчиков приветствуются.

Comment: я отказался от использования по этой причине, невозможно пока им пользоваться

Comment: Кажется это уже 4-ый ваш вопрос из серии "превью не работает". Каждый раз вам отвечают - "да, он не работает, юзайте девайс/эмулятор". Это длится годами. Почему?..

Comment: Потому что я хочу чтобы он заработал ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иногда layout-превью в Android Studio работает не совсем корректно, поэтому сильно ориентироваться на него не стоит.

Макеты лучше проверять непосредственно на устройстве/эмуляторе (особенно, если в layout-превью что-то отображается не так, как задано в xml).

Иногда, в случае глюков layout-превью, помогает либо обновление самого layout (что-нибудь убрал, сохранил, вернул назад, сохранил), либо чистка/пересборка проекта, либо перезагрузка самой Android Studio с инвалидацией кэша.